# ajax, php how to save correctly data

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I tried to send information via ajax about user_question and language input fields, but how to write correctly this element inside ajax javascript to save the table element value in database.

thank you.

the script element.

```
 <table id="myTable" class="table table-sm table-hover order-list">
        <thead>
            <tr>
              <td>User Question</td>
              <td>Language</td>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td class="col-md-9">' . HTML::inputField('user_question', null,  'placeholder="Write a short answer"'). '</td>
              <td class="col-md-2">' . HTML::inputField('language', null,  'placeholder="Language"') . '</td>
              <td class="col-sm-1"><a id="delete_row" class="deleteRow"></a></td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
            <td colspan="5">
              <input type="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-block " id="addrow" value="Add Row" />
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr></tr>
        </tfoot>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $("#addrow").on("click", function () {
        var newRow = $("<tr>");
        var cols = "";

        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_question' + counter + '"/></td>';
        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" name="language' + counter + '"/></td>';

        cols += '<td><input type="button" class="ibtnDel btn btn-md btn-danger " value="Delete"></td>';
        newRow.append(cols);
        $("table.order-list").append(newRow);
        counter++;

    // element pb            
    // var data = $("#new_product").serialize(); // form id or table id ?

    var dataString = 'user_question='+user_question+'language='+language;

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '{$ajax_url}',
        data    : dataString,
        success: function(data) {
            alert(data);
            $("p").text(data);

        }
    });

    $("table.order-list").on("click", ".ibtnDel", function (event) {
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();       
        counter -= 1
    });

});

</script>
```

Comment: If you have multiple inputs with the same name, you need to name them `name="user_question[]"` and `name="language[]"` so that PHP gets an array of all the inputs.

Comment: Ok, I try '        cols += '<td><input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_question[]" name="user_question[]' + counter + '"/></td>';
' and 'var dataString = "user_question[]="+user_question;' the result is : 'array(1) {
  ["user_question"]=>
  array(1) {
    [0]=>
    string(25) "[object HTMLInputElement]"
  }'

Answer (score 0):

Use like this to get php variables value inside javascript in .php page

```
  url: "<?php echo $ajax_url; ?>",
```

Also use `&` and symbol to add two or more param in your `dataString`